# Possible value for spring.data.elasticsearch.properties in application.properties

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

Where can I find the possible value for the configuration below about the client.

```
spring.data.elasticsearch.properties.*= # Additional properties used to configure the client.
```

I search in its document but doesn't seem to find the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can basically use all the settings that you can put in `elasticsearch.yml`, i.e.

```
spring.data.elasticsearch.properties.node.master: false
spring.data.elasticsearch.properties.node.data: false
spring.data.elasticsearch.properties.node.name: my-node
spring.data.elasticsearch.properties.node.attr.type: hot
spring.data.elasticsearch.properties.http.enabled: true
...
```

Comment: I see. Thanks for the answer.